# Cannot find the text inside `<span>`

Tags: html, ruby

I have an html as below:

```
<div class="info">
 <h5>
   <a href="/aaa/">aaa </a>
 </h5>
 <span class="date">
       8:27AM, Sep 30</span>     
</div>
```

I'm using Ruby and I want to get the text `"8:27AM, Sep 30"` that is inside `<span class="date">`. I cannot find it via the command below.

```
find('div.info span.date').text
```

Could you please tell me why it doesn't work? If I find the text inside `h5` with the following command, I can get `"aaa"` correctly.

```
find('div.info h5').text
```

**Full ruby code**

```
Then(/^you should see (\d+) latest items$/) do |arg1|
    within("div.top-feature-list") do
       # Validate images of those items exist, print report
       expect(all("img").size.to_s).to eq(arg1)
       puts "The number of items on the current site is " + (all("img").size.to_s)
       # List of all items' details (Image, Headline, Introduction, Identifier, Url)
       $i = 1
       while $i <= arg1.to_i do
          puts "Item no." + $i.to_s
          puts "        - Image:        " + find('ul.category-index li.item-' + $i.to_s + ' img')[:src].to_s
          puts "        - Headline: " + find('ul.category-index li.item-' + $i.to_s + ' div.info h5').text
          puts "        - Introduction: " + find('ul.category-index li.item-' + $i.to_s + ' div.summary').text
          puts "        - Url:      " + find('ul.category-index li.item-' + $i.to_s + ' div.info h5 a')[:href].to_s
          puts "        - Created Date " + find('ul.category-index li.item-' + $i.to_s + ' div.info span.date').text
          puts "        - Identifier:   " + find('ul.category-index li.item-' + $i.to_s + ' div.img a.section-name').text
          puts "        - Subsection:   " + find('ul.category-index li.item-' + $i.to_s + ' div.img a.section-name')[:href].to_s
          $i +=1
      end
    end
  end
```

**More html**

```
<div class="top-feature-list">  
 <ul class="category-index">
    <li class="group">
           <ul>
    <li class="item-1 left ">
        <a name="item-1"></a>
        <div class="img">
            <a href="/health-lifestyle/item1.html">
                <img alt="How to" src="//image_url">     
            </a>

            <a class="section-name test" href="/health-lifestyle/">
                LIFESTYLE </a>
        </div>
        <div class="info">
            <h5>

                <a href="/health-lifestyle/item1.html">
                    How to </a>

            </h5>
            <span class="date">
                10:20AM, Sep 30</span>

        </div>
        <div class="summary">

            <p>
                Summary text</p>

        </div>


    </li>
    ....
```

**env.rb**

```
require 'parallel_tests'
require 'capybara/cucumber'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'
require 'rspec'
```

Comment: What HTML parser are you using?

Comment: @lurker Sorry. Could you please tell me how I can find HTML parser that I'm using?

Comment: Maybe include more of your code? What is `find` operating on? Did you do a `require` statement to include a library? Did you install a `gem`?

Comment: @sawa an html is what I say now :)

Comment: @lurker I have added more of my code into the description. Could you please have a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsing HTML is super easy in Ruby.  All you need is to require two gems in your program:

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

# Set the page you are going to scan.
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://google.com/"))

# (Updated to reflect the date class provided in question)
# Extract specific elements via CSS selector.
# This first selects all everything that has span tag,
# then narrows down to anything with class of ".date"
# use .strip to remove any whitespace from HTML

page.css('span').css('.date').text.strip! 

# => outputs "8:27AM, Sep 30"
```

If you want more information on parsing HTML with Ruby, you need to be googling and reading about it.  One great resource to get you started is [here](http://ruby.bastardsbook.com/chapters/html-parsing/).

Answer (score 0):

use `find('.info > .date').text` to get content on the page.

```
    irb(main):035:0> find('.info').text
    => "aaa 8:27AM, Sep 30"
    irb(main):036:0> find('.info > .date').text
    => "8:27AM, Sep 30"
```